# In GLFW Open Gl, its created frame buffer does not change size when the screen is stretched

Tags: java

I have one problem with frame buffers. I'm writing a project in java using the library LWJGL 2. There the display is created in Display.class.  Just there when you create your own frame buffer on which I render the shadow map the screen changes the size of the buffer frame when you stretch the window. And also all works with a buffer of frames for reflection and refraction of water. But when I switched to LWJGL 3 I have a display created using the GLFW library. And there default frame buffer changes the size of the normally, and here is when I running an own frame buffer for water or shadows the I have the entire scene not changes the size of the from for this frame buffer.

As I understand the new frame buffer at the unbind the screen size of the original resolution. Supposedly the original screen resolution is 960x540 and I at the unbind of this permission, he puts.

No matter what I add a frame buffer for, it always does not measure the size when stretched.

Im tried use the GLFW getFramebufferSize:

```
   public void resizeFramebuffer(int width, int height)
   {
         IntBuffer framebufferSize = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(2);
         GLFW.nglfwGetFramebufferSize(this.window, MemoryUtil.memAddress(framebufferSize),MemoryUtil.memAddress(framebufferSize + 4);
         width = framebufferSize.get(0);
         height = framebufferSize.get(1);
         GlHelper.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
   }
```

But it works on the default frame buffer.
If anyone wants it here is my frame buffer object for shadows:

```
        public class ShadowFrameBuffer extends FrameBuffer
        {
            private final int WIDTH;
            private final int HEIGHT;
            private int fbo;
            private int shadowMap;

            /**
             * Initialises the frame buffer and shadow map of a certain size.
             */
            public ShadowFrameBuffer(long windowId, int width, int height) 
            {
                super(windowId, width, height); 
                this.WIDTH = width;
                this.HEIGHT = height;
                this.initialiseFrameBuffer();
            }

            /**
             * Deletes the frame buffer and shadow map texture when the game closes.
             */
            @Override
            public void cleanUp() 
            {
                GlHelper.glDeleteFramebuffers(fbo);
                GlHelper.glDeleteTextures(shadowMap);
            }

            /**
             * @return The ID of the shadow map texture.
             */
            public int getShadowMap() 
            {
                return shadowMap;
            }

            /**
             * Binds the frame buffer, setting it as the current render target. Anything
             * rendered after this will be rendered to this FBO, and not to the screen.
             */
            public void bindDrawFrameBuffer()
            {
                if(GlHelperError.isFramebufferSupported())
                {
                    TextureManager.bindTexture2d(0);
                    GlHelper.glBindFramebuffers(Framebuffer.FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
                    GlHelper.glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
                }
            }

            /**
             * Creates the frame buffer and adds its depth attachment texture.
             */
            public void initialiseFrameBuffer() 
            {
                this.fbo = createFrameBuffer();
                this.shadowMap = createDepthBufferAttachment(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
                this.unbindFrameBuffer();
            }

            /**
             * Creates a frame buffer and binds it so that attachments can be added to
             * it. The draw buffer is set to none, indicating that there's no colour
             * buffer to be rendered to.
             * 
             * @return The newly created frame buffer's ID.
             */
            public static int createFrameBuffer() 
            {
                int frameBuffer = GlHelper.glGenFramebuffers();
                GlHelper.glBindFramebuffers(Framebuffer.FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer);
                GlHelper.glDrawBuffers(Framebuffer.NONE);
                GlHelper.glReadBuffer(Framebuffer.NONE);
                return frameBuffer;
            }

            /**
             * Creates a depth buffer texture attachment.
             * 
             * @param width - the width of the texture.
             * @param height - the height of the texture.
             * @return The ID of the depth texture.
             */
            private static int createDepthBufferAttachment(int width, int height) 
            {
                int texture = GlHelper.glGenTextures();
                TextureManager.bindTexture2d(texture);
                GlHelper.glTexImage2D(0, Depth.DEPTH_COMPONENT16, width, height, 0,
                        Depth.DEPTH_COMPONENT, Texture.FLOAT, (ByteBuffer) null);
                GlHelper.glTexParameteri(Texture.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, Texture.NEAREST);
                GlHelper.glTexParameteri(Texture.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, Texture.NEAREST);
                GlHelper.glTexParameteri(Texture.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, Texture.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
                GlHelper.glTexParameteri(Texture.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, Texture.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
                GlHelper.glFramebufferTexture(Framebuffer.FRAMEBUFFER, Depth.DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, texture, 0);
                return texture;
            }
        }
```

If someone does not know what GlHelper is, then this is a class in which almost all Open Gl methods are connected to one class, so as not to write GL11, 12, 30, etc. Well, there are still some utilities.

Please help who than can. I would be very grateful. I myself am not new to Open Gl but I have faced this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what my mistake was. I used GLFW.nglfwGetFramebufferSize() which got the size of the buffer frame on not the screen itself. I should have used GLFW.glfwGetWindowSize(), that's how it works. If anyone has the same problem here is the full code:

```
public void resize()
{
    IntBuffer bufferedWidth = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1);
    IntBuffer bufferedHeight = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1);
    GLFW.glfwGetWindowSize(this.windowId, bufferedWidth, bufferedHeight);
}
```

And then in the decoupling of the buffer frame on which the scene is displayed, you need to add parameters from the saved buffer width and height:

```
public void unbindFrameBuffer()
{
    Gl30.glBindFramebuffers(Framebuffer.FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    Gl11.glViewport(0, 0, bufferedWidth.get(0), bufferedHeight.get(0));
}
```

And we need to make sure that all these operations occur in a while loop.

Comment: Just an hint, don't use `BufferUtils`, prefer `MemUtils`

Comment: What is the difference between `BufferUtils` and `MemUtils`?